# Replaced fixed variables in JS with inputs from HTML

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, input

I have downloaded some JavaScript code which creates a credit card paydown graph with and without overpayment. This code has fixed variables.

I would like to add HTML inputs for the user submit, however the script is connecting to a remote reference so I'm struggling to add a function to connect the script to HTML. Can HTML inputs be incorporated, if so, how?

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.3/clipboard.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.12.0/d3.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.moneymage.net/mm.min.js"></script>


  <div id="creditcard-interest-chart"></div>

  <!--want to add input variables here-->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //preventing me adding function below...
    moneymage.ready(() => {

      //fixed variables below...
      var creditCardBalance = 5500;
      var interestRate = 19.5 / 100.0;
      var minimumMonthlyRepaymentPercent = 2.5 / 100.0;
      var minimumMonthlyRepaymentFixed = 15.0;
      var optionalMonthlyRepaymentOverAndAboveMinimum = 175;
      var months = 25 * 12;

      moneymage.createCreditCardInterestChart(creditCardBalance,
        interestRate,
        minimumMonthlyRepaymentPercent,
        minimumMonthlyRepaymentFixed,
        optionalMonthlyRepaymentOverAndAboveMinimum,
        months,
        "creditcard-interest-chart");
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for user input you probably don't need to wait for moneymage to be ready, so you can just trigger the `moneymage.createCreditCardInterestChart` on a submit function for a form with the inputs you want.

This example would be the general idea to get you started: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-night-sl156?file=/index.html